# Why does not the process with Future finish on scala?

Tags: scala, exit, future

I saw something

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val numJobs = 50000
var numThreads = 10

// customize the execution context to use the specified number of threads
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads))


// define the tasks
val tasks = for (i <- 1 to numJobs) yield Future {
  // do something more fancy here
  i
}

// aggregate and wait for final result
val aggregated = Future.sequence(tasks)
val oneToNSum = Await.result(aggregated, 15.seconds).sum
```

However, this doesn't finish with Success.

I dont know why. I think maybe the Await.result is cause.

Please notice the solution.